# trackpad buttons in ubuntu 16.04 (left button is working as secondary button)

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

I bought Acer Predator 17" (Predator GX-792) for the deep learning research purpose, and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 as dual booting.

I think everything works well, except trackpad. There are two buttons in the trackpad, which should be supposed to work as `primary`(left) and `secondary`(right) button.

However, when I tested in the system mouse testing menu, I found that OS recognizes the left button as `secondary` and the right button as `middle`. How can I fix this? Could anyone please help?

- For information, I tested with an external USB mouse, and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the Predator 15, and the command

```
xinput set-button-map "SYNA7B99:00 06CB:7B99 Touchpad" 1 3 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

worked for me.

If your touchpad is called something different than `SYNA7B99:00 06CB:7B99 Touchpad`, you can find it with the command:

```
xinput -list
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too!  I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T410.  And though I have the same issue, mine is only intermittently doing this, but is still frustrating. Sometimes it is normal, other times I get the right click context menu when left clicking on the buttons on the bottom of the touchpad.

If yours is doing this all the time you can go into the System/Hardware/Mouse settings and check if it is set to left or right hand orientation.

Comment: Yes, in my case, it does always so. Mine is set to right-hand orientation. so I am really curious why it does.